# What are the daily earnings of Gopi given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Krishna and Rama can complete a job in $20$ and $30$ days.With the help of Gopi,they complete the work in $6$ days.If the total amount paid for the work is Rs $720$.What are the daily earnings of Gopi?

options:

a) $40$  b) $480$  c) $360$ d) $60$

MyApproach:

I did for Gopi (1-$6$/$20$+$6$/$30$)=$1$/$2$

Therefore,$1$/$2$ . $720$=$360$

This means Gopi earns daily Rs 360?

> I am getting confused here.Can Anyone guide me how to solve the problem correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The result is right for 6 days. In 1 day Gopi earns 60. My calculation was the following: Krishna, Rama and Gopi can complete $\frac{1}{20},\frac{1}{30}$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ of the job in one day. Together they can finish the whole job in 6 day. Thus the equation is

$6\cdot \left(\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{30} + \frac{1}{x}\right) =1 (\text{job})$

Solving for x gives $x=12$

Therefore the relations of productivity is $\frac{1}{20}:\frac{1}{30}$ : $\frac{1}{12}$

The least common multiple is 60.

$\frac{3}{60}:\frac{2}{60}$ : $\frac{5}{60}\Rightarrow 3:2:5$

In total we have $10(=3+2+5)$ parts. The half of it belongs to Gopi. Therefore Gopi is productive as Krishna and Rama together and thus he gets the half of the total earnings. In one day Gopi earns 60.

Comment: Ans given is 60

Comment: @Jack Gopi earns 360 in 6 days and therefore 60 per day.